Odoo quantity duplication after returning an inventory IN move
Hello everybody I have installed Odoo 18 on my machine then I created a purchase order which accordingly created an inventory IN move But when I tries to return the IN move the recieved quantity in PO is duplicated instead of zero
need your help

the right place for your no-code issue is https://www.odoo.com/forum/suport-1

we checked on odoo runbot, and it's working fine in the latest 18.0 Build, so please update your odoo18 code with the latest.

I  just installed the odoo 18 4 days ago on my machine ,do you mean that  a new build is released?
